# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to update some field in my data table. While using the given below code shows one error. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignJrEngineersTeamTableAdapter tm;
tm = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignJrEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = tm.UpdateTeam(AssignedTeam,userName,DateTime.Now,ID); // error popup here
```

SQL:

```
UPDATE tbl_AutoAssignJrEngineersTeam 
SET Assigned_Team = @Assigned_Team, 
    Updated_By = @Updated_By, 
    Updated_Date = @Updated_Date 
WHERE (Id = @Id)
```

DataBase:

[image]

Comment: Somewhere you have an `int` and try to cast it explicitly or implicitly to a `DataTable`. My guess would be the `tm.UpdateTeam` method returns an int.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' ? c#4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839755/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-int-to-string-c4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`TableAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx.aspx)-method returns an `int` which is the count of affected records, so how many records were updated. But you are assigning it to a `DataTable` variable.

```
int updatedRows = tm.UpdateTeam(AssignedTeam,userName,DateTime.Now,ID);
```

You either have to

- load the table again with the appropriate `GetData`- or `Fill(dt)` methods from the TableAdapter
- or update the rows in the table and use `tm.Update(modifiedDataTable)` instead which will execute the `UpdateCommand` of the adapater for every row with [`RowState=Modified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx).