# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string' ? c#4

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

while running the given below code, getting an error. I have to perform delete operation through gridview.

code:

```
protected void gvEdit_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        string Emp_ID = gvEdit.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

        int EId = Convert.ToInt32(Emp_ID); // error popup here
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_EmployeeToTeamTableAdapter tm;
        tm = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_EmployeeToTeamTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        tm.GetDelete(EId);
        BindData();
    }
```

DB:

[image]

SQL:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_EmployeeToTeam WHERE (Emp_ID = @Emp_ID)
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What does `GetDelete()` method do and what is the type of `EId`?

Comment: if its the top two lines then why do you need to convert it at all? you seem to just be making a string to convert it back again

Comment: Emp_ID varchar why??

Comment: What's the definition of `GetDelete()`?

Comment: @StephanBauer : GetDelete  definition added above. Please check

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar : My employee Id is strating from EMP001, EMP002..etc. So I have used varchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that `GetDelete` expects a string but you're passing an `int`. I think so because it seems to be the parameter for `Emp_ID` which is a `varchar`.   So you could simply pass that `string` which you already had in:

```
gvEdit.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

But if it's supposed to be an `int`, why don't you use the correct data type in the database?

[Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

**Update**

> My employee Id is strating from EMP001, EMP002..etc. So how can I use
> integer data type

Why do you store always `EMP` at the beginning? You could also omit that and use `int` as type which would be more efficient and fail-safe. Then you could prepend `EMP` where you need to *display* it.

However, if you don't want to change that and `Emp_ID` contains only the ID without `EMP` you can use string concatenation:

```
tm.GetDelete("EMP" + Emp_ID);
```

Comment: My employee Id is strating from EMP001, EMP002..etc. So how can I use integer data type

Comment: @Vipin: why does it have them? If they always have `EMP` at the beginning you could also omit that and use an `int` as type. Then you could prepend `EMP` where you need to _display_ it. I have edited my answer.